utilize computer resources on RLLIB config.build().train() effectively
I am trying to learn what are the best practices for determining parameters that utilize computer resources effectively in RlLib. On my laptop, I have 16 cpu cores and 1 gpu. I tried running the script below. (specifically, parameters in the .env_runners)
import time
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPOConfig

config = (
    PPOConfig()
    .api_stack(
        enable_rl_module_and_learner=True,
        enable_env_runner_and_connector_v2=True,
    )
    .env_runners(num_env_runners=15,
 num_envs_per_env_runner=1,
 num_cpus_per_env_runner=1,
 num_gpus_per_env_runner=0,
 rollout_fragment_length="auto")
    .environment("CartPole-v1")
    .learners(num_learners=1, num_gpus_per_learner=1)
    .training(model={"uses_new_env_runners": True})

)

algo = config.build()

start = time.process_time()
for i in range(10):
    result = algo.train()
print(time.process_time() - start)

First of all I just want to verify my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong or if there is anything missing. One num_env_runners represent a box that contains a copy of the policy to be trained as well as a copy of the environment to be trained on. The policy and environment interact with each other episodes after episodes until the sum of samples across all the num_env_runners has met the quota defined by train_batch_size(default value: 4000). Then they concatenate these samples and pass them to a learner which train the policy using back-propagation (number of learner is defined by num_learners). Then the env_runners obtain a new updated version of the policy and repeats.
Question 1
Back to the code, the print statement returns about 2.5, and if I completely remove .env_runners() from the configuration. I get around the same number regardless. And I also tried setting num_env_runners to 1, 8, 15, still get around the same number. Maybe it is because the backpropagation on the learner and the sampling for next learning batch on the env_runner runs simultaneously. And the sampling stage is always quicker so it really didn't matter how efficient the sampling is? Please correct me if I am wrong.
Question 2
Assuming I have solved the above problem. When should i use multiple num_envs_per_env_runner and num_cpus_per_env_runners? num_gpus_per_env_runner should always be 0 is that correct? Since u want it for backpropagation?
Question 3
Please enlighten me if there are any parameters or practices I have missed that could help with reducing training time.
